# Ruby FFI - trapping C calls to exit()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins, ffi

I have a Rails application with a FFI binding to a custom RPC system.  Unfortunately, the C code calls `exit()` when it is unable to connect to the RPC server, terminating the entire Rails application.

Is it possible to trap calls to `exit()` in Ruby? I'd rather not have to change the C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot trap a function call. However maybe you can link the C code with a dummy `exit()` function that will not actually exit.

The cleaner solution is by far to change the C code to give it a proper library behaviour.

You could also fork in ruby before doing the RPC call, a bit on the expensive side performance wise but would solve the issue too...